# React: Wait until all childs are avaiable and call a function once afterwards

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Solved, See **UPDATE** below. You can use this code as reference to implement something simillar

---

Lets say I have a parent react component (ES6):

**Parent**

```
import ChildDiv from './ChildDiv'

export default React.createClass({
  displayName: 'ParentDiv',

  getInitialState () {
    nodesLoadedToCanvas: 0,
    workedOnParentOnceAfterAllChildrenWereLoaded: false
  },

  onChildNodeDidMount () {
    let nodeCount = this.state.nodesLoadedToCanvas + 1
    this.state.nodesLoadedToCanvas = nodeCount
    console.log('Mount ' + this.state.nodesLoadedToCanvas + ' nodes so far')
  },

  render () {
    const {children} = this.props // 'children' is a model collection

    return (
      <div id='ParentDiv'>
      {children.map((childDiv) => 
        <ChildDiv data={childDiv} key={childDiv.id} onRender={this.onChildNodeDidMount}/>
      )}
      </div>
    )
  },

  componentDidMount () {
    console.log('Parent did mount')
  },

  componentDidUpdate () {
    let allNodesArePresent = (this.state.nodesLoadedToCanvas === this.props.children.length)
    if (!this.state.workedOnParentOnceAfterAllChildrenWereLoaded) {
      console.log('Do something')
      this.state.workedOnParentOnceAfterAllChildrenWereLoaded= true
    }
  }
})
```

And a child-component like this

**Child**

```
export default React.createClass({
  displayName: 'ParentDiv',

  render () {
    const {data} = this.props

    return (
      <div id='ParentDiv'>
        data.name
      </div>
    )
  },

  componentDidMount () {
    console.log('ChildDiv did mount')
    this.props.onRender() // tell parent that child did mount
  },

  componentDidUpdate () {
  }
})
```

Why is my console saying

```
Parent did Mount
ChildDiv did Mount
ChildDiv did Mount
ChildDiv did Mount
```

And not

```
ChildDiv did Mount
ChildDiv did Mount
ChildDiv did Mount
Parent did Mount
```

?

How can I make react call a function after the full parent (and all it's childs) are rendered?

**UPDATE**

I solved this with the Input of @nash_ag by adding a `onRender={this.onChildNodeDidMount}` Parameter to my  tag (see above), call the function in ChildDiv in `componentDidMount()` and can now decide if all nodes were loaded in my parents `componentDidUpdate()` method. I updated my code above.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you want to do? The order of the logs make sense since a child cannot be in the document before its parent. However, when componentDidMount is called, all the components are already rendered.

Comment: I want to connect the childs with a JSPlumb Connection. For that they have to be present on the DOM. If I put the connect-Operation in `componentDidUpdate()` my Connections will get get drawn (after some failed attempts) but will be re-drawn every time the component updates. This kills my performance and is not nice...

Comment: It should work fine in componentDidMount

Comment: Nope. JSPlumb prints to my console `Cannot establish connection - source does not exist'

Comment: Mmh. I don't know anymore how jsPlumb works. How are you telling jsplumb which elements to use?

Comment: Well this looks like a workaround @Benvorth. The question still stands. Why CDM of parent is called before the ones of his children?

Comment: for react native i used onLayout

Comment: What todo when stateless components ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can probably use the `componentDidUpdate()` to check if all the children are finished, as this is called every time you render a dynamic child.

Once the last one is received (comparison from props), you can then go ahead with the further processing.

Comment: Thank you for the Input. Do you have an idea on how to best determine if all childs did render?

Comment: `React.Children` is the one which might be able to help. Check: 
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children

Comment: This worked perfectly for me as I needed a way to know when a child props were updated. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, be careful not to cause an infinite loop by setting state within componentDidUpdate() without some sort of a break to stop it from setting state everytime. I know because i did it myself.